# CAOpenGLLayer has clipped image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mobile, calayer

I am struggling with CAOpenGLLayer.

My problem is, when I resize window smaller than initial size, internal image is clipped (top or right part is gone). I have tried to adjust glViewport() or glOrtho(), but it does not work. Please give me advise.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "MyOpenGLLayer.h"

@interface CALayerTestAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation CALayerTestAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[window contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];
    CALayer *contentLayer = [[window contentView] layer];
    MyOpenGLLayer *layer = [MyOpenGLLayer layer];
    [contentLayer addSublayer:layer];

    layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
    layer.bounds = contentLayer.bounds;
    layer.frame = contentLayer.frame;
    layer.autoresizingMask = kCALayerWidthSizable | kCALayerHeightSizable;
    layer.asynchronous = YES;
}
@end
```

With following CAOpenGLLayer subclass:

```
@interface MyOpenGLLayer : CAOpenGLLayer 
@end

@implementation MyOpenGLLayer
- (void)drawInCGLContext:(CGLContextObj)glContext 
         pixelFormat:(CGLPixelFormatObj)pixelFormat 
        forLayerTime:(CFTimeInterval)timeInterval 
         displayTime:(const CVTimeStamp *)timeStamp {
NSRect bounds = NSRectFromCGRect([self bounds]);
GLfloat minX, minY, maxX, maxY;        
minX = NSMinX(bounds);
minY = NSMinY(bounds);
maxX = NSMaxX(bounds);
maxY = NSMaxY(bounds);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glViewport(minX, minY, maxX, maxY);
glOrtho(minX, maxX, minY, maxY, -1.0, 1.0);

glClearColor(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);         
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

const size_t unit = 40;
for (int x = 0; x<[self bounds].size.width; x+=unit) 
    for (int y = 0; y<[self bounds].size.height; y+=unit)
        if ((x + y)/unit & 1) 
            glRectd(x, y, x+unit, y+unit);
glFlush();

[super drawInCGLContext:glContext pixelFormat:pixelFormat 
           forLayerTime:timeInterval displayTime:timeStamp];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and searched the documentation. You just need to add a call to `[caLayer setNeedsDisplay]` somewhere.

I made your code work just adding `[self setNeedsDisplay];` inside `drawInCGLContext:pixelFormat:forLayerTime:displayTime:`, but I'm sure there is a better place for that (maybe a run loop, or another timing method).

Without `setNeedsDisplay` the result is quite unpredictable: it seems that OpenGL draws correctly, *glViewport* maps the rendering area correctly, but the CALayer keeps the content area the same and copies part of the updated OpenGL data in it, even if `bounds`, `frame` and `contentRect` have the right values. Switching to `kCAGravityResize` (in the attempt of forcing the content area to fill the layer) produced even stranger results, with contents being partially scaled. I suppose this is part of the implementation of *CAOpenGLLayer*, dividing into independent procedures the OpenGL drawing process and the Core Animation's one.